# mysql server for working online without using local as for team work

Tags: mysql, xampp, teamwork-projects

I wanted to use my `xampp` local server with my friend so that we can make database together as a team. How to do this?

Like we have google words, github for codes pushing and writing etc.
I know purchased website have integrated database management but, I am not purchasing any one.

I search on google but out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing performance testing, the free tier offered by most cloud providers should be sufficient, however you really need to run this on Linux with VPN access.

But if you're doing collaborative development work you *REALLY* need to be using version control. That includes use for your DDL. Exending that to your test data should be trivial.